# IntelliJ formatting and TSLint are in clinche when it comes to ES2015 imports

Tags: intellij-idea, formatting, tslint

I've a TypeScript file in IntelliJ. This file is observed by TSLint. Unfortunately we commonly use the "ctrl + alt + L" formatting in IntelliJ. This currently changes an ES2015 import from:

```
import {component} from 'library';
```

to

```
import {component} from "library";
```

*Notice that the '' around library are replaced with "".*

However, TSLint doesn't like the second form and suggests to replace the "" with ''. This creates an endless loop :)

How do I tell IntelliJ to format the imports with '' instead of ""?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **2016.3.x**, choose "Single quote" in `Preferences | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript`, `Other/Generated Code/Quote Marks`

For **2017.1**, you need changing `Preferences | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript | Punctuation` to `Use <single> quotes <always>`